# How go to prev search text in minibuffer?

Tags: isearch

Emacs 26.1, Ido , smex,

Open *scratch* buffer.

`C-s` to find text `file`
Here result:
[image]

```
C-g
```

Now I want to find another text: `text`

Here result:
[image]

Nice. It's work fine.
But now I want to backward in search history. 
So I need again to search text (in minibuffer): `file`

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can search backwards with <kbd>C-r</kbd>, and you can go backward and forward **through search history** with <kbd>M-p</kbd> and <kbd>M-n</kbd> respectively.

Comment: You might want to emphasize the last part - it's the answer to the question. I don't think OP is also asking about search direction.

Comment: When I press "M-p" or "M-n" I get message in "M-p/M-n is underfined". If I input command "previous-history-element" I get another error: "Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil"

Comment: Does the problem persist when you run `emacs -q`?

Comment: Yes. With "emacs  -Q" I also get this error. I use Emacs 26.1 on Windows 10 (64 bit)

Comment: Are you typing these commands in the minibuffer for `isearch`?

Comment: Yes this command in minibuffer